# Java Swing Add JPanel to JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, null-layout-manager

#### The Situation

I am currently trying to build a 2D game with Java's Swing. For this, I have my main class `Puzzle` which is subclassing `JFrame`. To my frame I add my main `JPanel` which consists of several `JPanel`s added together (each of them being a new piece).

**EDIT 2:** `PlayingField` is my model which will store the current location of each piece.
One can select a piece with the mouse (the plan is to highlight it) and move it with the arrow keys as long as the next step (a full cell, so approx. 100 pixel) isn't the location of one of the other pieces. As of right now, `PlayingField`does not store any data since the pieces are missing.

```java
private void createAndShowGui() {
    // The playing-field with a 4x6 grid.
    PlayingField field = new PlayingField(4, 6);
    JPanel mainPanel = new ComputerView(field);
    
    setTitle("Puzzle");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(400, 600);
    add(mainPanel);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

The method above will create my frame and adds the main panel. The following method is my main panel which adds several `JPanel`s to itself.

```java
public ComputerView(PlayingField field) {
    this.field = field;
    this.setLayout(null);

    JPanel topLeft = new GamingPiece(PlayingField.TOP_LEFT);
    add(topLeft);
    
    JPanel topRight = new GamingPiece(PlayingField.TOP_RIGHT);
    add(topRight);
    
    JPanel bottomLeft = new GamingPiece(PlayingField.BOTTOM_LEFT);
    add(bottomLeft);
}
```

Each `GamingPiece` or rather my sub-`JPanel`s are drawing a basic piece (I only drawing one and rotating the others, since all consists of the same arbitrary shape). The `GamingPiece` class also subclasses `JPanel` and invokes the `JPanel#paintComponent()` method to draw the piece.

```java
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    g2.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    g2.fillPolygon(pieceX, pieceY, pieceX.length);
}
```

#### The Problem And My Questions

Since I am pretty new to Java I really do not know how to do it properly. If I add my pieces by creating a new object and adding it to the main panel, it won't show all of them, only the last one added. Some don't even seem to work, even if they're the only ones added (to explain my situation: I have for pieces which are the same arbitrary shape just rotated differently but using `Graphics2D#rotate()` doesn't seem to work fine).

I hope I explained my situation and my problem well enough fo you guys to help me. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

#### My Codes

**Puzzle.java**

```java
package programming.schimmler;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import programming.schimmler.model.PlayingField;
import programming.schimmler.view.ComputerView;

public class Puzzle extends JFrame {
    
...
Invoking the createAndShowGui()
...
    
private void createAndShowGui() {
    // The playing-field with a 4x6 grid.
    PlayingField field = new PlayingField(4, 6);
    JPanel mainPanel = new ComputerView(field);
    
    setTitle("Puzzle");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(400, 600);
    add(mainPanel);
    setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**ComputerView.java**

```java
package programming.schimmler.view;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import programming.schimmler.model.PlayingField;

public class ComputerView extends JPanel {

...
Instance variables
....

public ComputerView(PlayingField field) {
    this.field = field;
    this.setLayout(null);

    JPanel topLeft = new GamingPiece(PlayingField.TOP_LEFT);
    add(topLeft);
    
    JPanel topRight = new GamingPiece(PlayingField.TOP_RIGHT);
    add(topRight);
    
    JPanel bottomLeft = new GamingPiece(PlayingField.BOTTOM_LEFT);
    add(bottomLeft);
    }
}
```

**GamingPiece.java**

```java
package programming.schimmler.view;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import programming.schimmler.model.PlayingField;

/**
 * 
 */
public class GamingPiece extends JPanel {

...

public GamingPiece(int type) {
    switch (type) {
    // Need to draw each polygon from different coordinates since rotating did not work yet.
    case PlayingField.TOP_LEFT:
        pieceX = new int[] { 100, 100, 300, 300, 200, 200, 100 };
        pieceY = new int[] { 100, 100, 100, 200, 200, 300, 300 };
        break;
    case PlayingField.TOP_RIGHT:
        pieceX = new int[] { 400, 400, 300, 300, 200, 200 };
        pieceY = new int[] { 0, 200, 200, 100, 100, 0 };
        break;
    case PlayingField.BOTTOM_LEFT:
        pieceX = new int[] { 0, 200, 200, 100, 100, 0 };
        pieceY = new int[] { 400, 400, 300, 300, 200, 200 };
        break;
    case PlayingField.BOTTOM_RIGHT:
        pieceX = new int[] { 400, 400, 300, 300, 200, 200 };
        pieceY = new int[] { 400, 200, 200, 300, 300, 400 };
        break;
    case PlayingField.SQUARE:
        pieceX = new int[] { 100, 300, 300, 100 };
        pieceY = new int[] { 100, 100, 300, 300 };
        break;
    }
    
    setLayout(null);
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    g2.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    g2.fillPolygon(pieceX, pieceY, pieceX.length);
    }
}
```

These classes above are the **only** classes interacting with my GUI, no other classes take part.

Comment: I see the problem.. `this.setLayout(null);` **Use. Layouts.** General tip: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Please add a [mcve].   Without one, we can only guess at the problem(s).  `setLayout(null)` comes to mind as one possibility.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I actually wanted to use Swing without a layout manager for [absolute positioning](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html).

Comment: @AJNeufeld This is actually my whole code but some instance variables declaration. I could add my whole code, but this is actually the important parts.

Comment: I want a flying pony that excretes ice-cream. Now we've both discussed our unattainable dreams, you should fix that code by using layouts. Or if you can't manage it, show your attempt as an MCVE / SSCCE.

Comment: *"I could add my whole code"* Nobody.. **nobody** has suggested to post the entire code. Did you follow and read those links? What confused you?

Comment: @AndrewThompson see my edited post for my MCVE. I tried using a layout but as of now, I wasn't able to get it to work so I went back to null layout manager.

Comment: If your game area is a grid, you might be better off using a [GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GridLayout.html).

Comment: What is `PlayingField`?  Is it an `enum` or a `class` with static members?  Is it a model holding where the pieces are, or where they should go?  Do you want the pieces to be dragged around with the mouse?  Or do pieces move like a 4x4 “magic 16” puzzle, where clicking a piece could cause a move of a full 100 pixel grid step?  Until we understand what you are trying to do, we may as well be threading a needle while wearing oven mitts; possible, but really really hard.

Comment: @AJNeufeld I'm sorry for making this so hard for you guys. I'm just pretty new to this site and programming. *"PlayingField is my model which will store the current location of each piece. One can select a piece with the mouse (the plan is to highlight it) and move it with the arrow keys as long as the next step (a full cell, so approx. 100 pixel) isn't the location of one of the other pieces. As of right now, PlayingFielddoes not store any data since the pieces are missing."*, would be the missing information.

Comment: "I'm sorry for making this so hard for you guys"  :  I can only repeat the advice you got: mvce. Not the whole code (That is what M stands for) but code that we can copy-paste and run (E).  It is  clearer and shorter than the attempt to describe the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overcomplicating things by trying to add `JPanel` puzzle pieces to your `JPanel` puzzle board.  Problems will rapidly become apparent with your non-rectangular puzzle pieces, like the `TOP_LEFT` shape, which has a cut-out from the lower right side of the piece.  When it comes time to overlap the puzzle pieces, to fit the cut-away portions together, the piece added later will occlude pieces drawn earlier.

For instance, if you try to nest a TOP_LEFT piece (A) and a BOTTOM_RIGHT piece (B) together.

```
 AAAAAA BBB   
 AAAAAA BBB
 AAA BBBBBB
 AAA BBBBBB
```

You will only see:

```
+---+------+
|AAA|   BBB|
|AAA|   BBB|
|AAA|BBBBBB|
|AAA|BBBBBB|
+---+------+
```

The overlapping area will be drawn by only one of the panels.  The entire area of the B piece, including the blank space, will be drawn in the area of the second piece, on top of whatever the A piece hoped to display.

You might be able to get around this by setting the `JPanel` to be transparent, and not calling `super.paintComponent()` which paints the entire component the background colour.  But then you still have to draw the shape on the `JPanel`, and position the `JPanel` properly on the parent `JPanel`.

Forget panels within panels!  Just **draw** the pieces on the parent `JPanel`.

Example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Puzzle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Puzzle::new);
    }

    private final static int shape_x[] = { -100, 100, 100, 0, 0, -100 };
    private final static int shape_y[] = { -100, -100, 0, 0, 100, 100 };

    public Puzzle() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Puzzle");
        frame.setSize(600, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        View view = new View();
        frame.setContentPane(view);

        Shape l_shape = new Polygon(shape_x, shape_y, shape_x.length);
        view.pieces.add(new Piece(Color.YELLOW, l_shape,   0, 100, 100));
        view.pieces.add(new Piece(Color.GREEN,  l_shape, 180, 300, 300));
        view.pieces.add(new Piece(Color.RED,    l_shape,  65, 450, 145));

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class View extends JPanel {

    final List<Piece> pieces = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D gc = (Graphics2D) g;
        for (Piece piece : pieces)
            piece.draw(gc);
    }
}

class Piece {
    final Color color;
    final Shape shape;
    final int angle;

    int x, y;   // Move pieces by by changing these

    Piece(Color color, Shape shape, int angle, int x, int y) {
        this.color = color;
        this.shape = shape;
        this.angle = angle;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    void draw(Graphics2D gc) {
        AffineTransform tf = gc.getTransform();
        gc.translate(x, y);
        gc.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle));
        gc.setColor(color);
        gc.fill(shape);
        gc.setTransform(tf);
    }
}
```

Note that this is also a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example.  Minimal: No `package` statement; No extra `HashSet` and `Set` imports which aren't used;  doesn't try to do anything except show 3 game pieces.  It is complete: a single file you can compile, and run.  It is verifiable: you can run it and see it shows 3 game pieces.

As a bonus, it shows `Graphics2D.rotate()` working, with one piece rotated 180°, and another rotated at an angle that is not appropriate for your puzzle but useful in demonstrating the that rotate works just fine.

Comment: Thank you so much for the code (which worked like a charm!) and the tips, highly appreciated it! :-) I'm just running into one more question: I need to select one piece by a mouse click. I figured `getComponentAt()`would do the trick, but this returns the whole view. Is it possible to only get the corresponding element (e.g. the top-left piece) and save it to an variable to e.g. change the location?

Comment: " I'm just running into one more question" please post a new question.

Comment: @AJNeufeld maybe you tell me how I can move a drawn shape? E.g. when interacting with them with `KeyEvent`s so if I press the arrow-key up, it should move 100 pixel up?

Comment: This posted question is "Java Swing Add JPanel to JPanel".  Asked, answered & accepted. It is not about hit detection to figure out which piece a mouse is over, or about how to move/animate pieces.  Posting a new question for each of those does several things.  1) Keeps the Question-Answer aspect clean; someone searching for `JPanel` in `JPanel` doesn't have to sort through unrelated answers/information.  2) Allows other people to earn reputation for on-topic answers on a new post.  3) Improve your own reputation by posting more quality questions and accepting a quality answer on each.